# $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM on a rotating three-sphere

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

In the following paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9911124, the authors claim that the dual field theory to the five dimensional Kerr-AdS black hole is a $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM on a rotating three-sphere at finite temperature. I'm trying to understand if is that particular dual field theory living only on the boundary? The spacetime on the boundary can be obtained by taking a conformal limit?  Which theory do we expect to live in the bulk? The formula (3.1) presents the partition function of the filed theory, there are the angular velocities defined at the infinity? I would expect it as the field theory lives on the boundary.